# Prove that there are no integer solutions x,y to the following system of equations using mod 4 arithmetic:

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, linear-diophantine-equations

So i was given a question stated in the title and I have to show this for

A)$2x+7y=3$

B)$3x+ 8y = 3$

C)$4x + 9y = 5$

I understand how to use the linear diophantine equation to solve these questions but what confuses me is the "using the mod 4 arithmetic" in the question. What exactly does that mean and how would you do it?

Comment: It means that all coefficients are taken modulo $4$, and then it is shown that the resulting system has no solution in $\mathbb Z_4$

Comment: For example equation $B$ becomes $3x=3$ , which implies $x=1$ in $\mathbb Z_4$. And equation $C$ becomes $y=1$. This contradicts with equation $A$, which becomes $2x+3y=3$.

Comment: @Peter I don't really follow what you mean in $\Bbb Z_4$

Comment: Divide the coefficients by $4$ and denote the remainder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a **system** of equations it implies more than one equation and that you are supposed to find a solution that satisfies all of them simultaneously. I presume the system consists of those three equations, **not** that you are supposed to "show this for" each of them individually.

What they mean is to reduce both sides modulo $4$ and see what it gives.

$2x + 3y \equiv 3 \pmod{4}$.

$3x \equiv 3 \pmod{4}$.

$y \equiv 1 \pmod{4}$.

You can easily check that $x \equiv 1 \pmod{4}$ based on the second equation but that and the third equation contradict the first.